# Is the grid_terrain resolution in the units of the point cloud?

Tags: r, dem, lidar, resolution, lidr

My las tiles are all in a coordinate system that uses US feet, so if the `res` parameter for `grid_terrain()` is set to 1, is the output 1-ft resolution? I figured this is the case, but my professor wondered if the function only uses meter units, in which case the output is 1-m resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In lidR, inputs are unitless. The software only makes stupid comparisons between the coordinates of the points and the input values. So if you ask for grouping by 1 unit it is 1 unit of the point-cloud. It works the same if you want to query point above `x` or anything else. The CRS of the input point-cloud is always propagated and preserved in the outputs.